# Remoteapps won't launch

Tags: windows-server-2012, remoteapp

I have two 2012 RDS servers, which host RemoteApps with RDWEB.

On some computers, even if it worked before, the remoteapp icons stop working. (You can click them all you want, nothing happens). Even reboots and running windows update does not work.

The exact same computer can launch the same application when placing the .RDP file on the desktop.
Also the same computer can launch the application when logging in to an 2008 R2 RDS with the same apps published.  (In this case the client is using Windows 7)

Other users can use the 2012 RDWEB server just fine at the exact same time; so it must be a local issue.

Does anyone have any idea where to look?